# Java split string by whitespace and punctuation but include only punctuation in result

Tags: java, regex

`hello-world how are you?`

should result in

```
hello
-
world
how
are 
you
?
```

This is the code I tried

```
String str = "Hello-world how are you?";
Arrays.stream(str.split("\\b+")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: please provide your code, I don't really understand your question

Comment: At least add `hello` in your input

Comment: @ronald added code. hope you now can understand question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for splitting:

```
String str = "hello-world how are you?";
Arrays.stream(str.split("\\p{javaWhitespace}+|(?=\\p{P})|(?<=\\p{P})")).forEach(System.err::println);
```

Here `\\p{Z}+|(?=\\p{P})|(?<=\\p{P})` splits on any unicode whitespace or with the help of lookaheads it asserts if previous or next character is a punctuation character.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jdqmCS/4)

**Output:**

```
hello
-
world
how
are
you
?
```

Comment: Not quite all whitespace, as `\p{Z}` does not match a tab.

Comment: You're right. `\p{javaWhitespace}` is better than `\p{Z}`

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Hello-world how are you?";
Arrays.stream(str.split("\\b+")).forEach(w -> {
    if (!w.equals(" "))
        System.out.println(w);
});
```

Comment: To eliminate `if` you can simply use `filter`. This would allow you to write your solution as `Arrays.stream(str.split("\\b+")).filter(w->!w.equals(" ")).forEach(System.out::println);`.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler regex solution is possible with a *matching approach*:

```
String str = "Hello-world how are yóu?";
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?U)\\w+|\\p{Punct}").matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(res);
// => [Hello, -, world, how, are, yóu, ?]
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/6b7Qli)

**Details**:

- `(?U)` - a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` modifier (so that `\w` could match Unicode letters)
- `\\w+` - 1+ word chars (letters, digits, or `_` - that can be subtracted by using `[\\w&&[^_]]` or `[^\\W_]`)
- `|` - or
- `\\p{Punct}` - a punctuation symbol (may be replaced with `[\\p{P}\\p{S}]`).

Answer (score -1):

Use the  `split`, this broke in separator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "hello - word bla bla bla";
        String[] values = test.split(" ");

        for (String element : values) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `hello-world` is connected

Comment: see StringTokenizer  
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html