# +count the number of words in string

Tags: java, string

I want to count the number of words in a given String. For example, we are parsing a large text document.

I have used this method

`noOfWords = countedStegoText.trim().split(" +").length;`

but what about if the text contain two kind of spaces for example( "U+0020" and "U+205F) how I can count the number of word in this case?

Comment: "\\s+" and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286467/java-split-string-by-whitespace-and-punctuation-but-include-only-punctuation-in

Answer (score 0):

.split(...) can take a regular expression, simply build one that includes all your matching characters.

For example:

```
"hello world-foo_bar".split("[ |\\-|_]")
```

Results in an array of length 4

```
["hello", "world", "foo", "bar"]
```

To use Unicode characters in RegEx you use \u####, so you're looking for something like:

```
countedStegoText.trim().split("[\u0020|\u205F]").length
```